# Blend flat color of background-image

Tags: css, background

I would like to blend multiple background colors using background-blend-mode: multiply; but it doesn't work.

Here is a demo:

```css
.ye {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(red 0 0), linear-gradient(yellow 0 0);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="ye">

</div>
```

Comment: it does, you are probably not familiar with blending? the result of multiply of red and yellow is red

Comment: *The resultant color is always at least as dark as either the source or destination color. Multiplying any color with black results in black. Multiplying any color with white preserves the original color.* --> https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#blendingmultiply .. yellow (#ffff00) red(#ff0000) so the result is (#ff0000) red

Comment: Ok ok I see, but what if I want to get orange ? (red + yellow = orange), i thought i had to multiply them...

Comment: I invite you to read more about how blending work. You need to understand the logic behind each value to know which one to pick. It's not as simple as you may think.

Comment: ok thanks i will check it right now :)